# Whenever I upload an icon on jlabel and run the jform. It doesn't display and gives an error in the output

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jframe

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toExternalForm()" because "location" is null

This error occurs.
I use netbeans 12.6

[![stacktrace screenshot][1]][1]

Edit: I apologise for the lack of decorum in presenting the code and also sorry for the delay. The problem is basic in nature. My jform runs and displays 'Except' whenever I insert in images and gifs as icons for jlabel.

CODE:

public class Login extends javax.swing.JFrame {

```
/**
 * Creates new form Login
 */
public Login() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/Login_ani.gif"))); // NOI18N

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(94, 94, 94)
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addContainerGap(96, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(128, 128, 128)
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addContainerGap(172, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Login().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1bmT.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iar3F.png

Comment: Please don't post images of text, edit your question and copy and paste the error and your code.

Comment: We can’t tell you what’s wrong with your code if you don’t show us your code.  Edit your question and add the code which is causing the error.